# Can't remove Apps Script projects from containers

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a container (google sheets file) that is associated with a script project. I'd like to remove the project from the container, but when I click into Overview and hit the trashcan, I get a status message at the bottom of the screen: "Failed to modify , and I'm kicked back out into script.google.com, where the project still exists. When I go into Apps Script from the container file, the script project is indeed still there.

How do I remove a script from it's associated container? Or just delete it entirely?

Comment: Can you try accessing it using the incognito window and do the deletion again?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So, this is just my guess. I apologize for this. As another approach, when you delete the Google Apps Script project using an API, what result will you obtain? Please try to delete it with [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/delete).

Comment: Please access the above URL and set the Google Apps Script project ID to `fileId`. And, if the file is put into the shared drive, please set `supportsAllDrives` to `true` and click "EXECUTE". By this, the container-bound script can be deleted. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize. If an error occurs, I expected that the reason for your current issue might be able to be obtained from the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the container owner can delete a bounded script; however, some features might not work well when the bounded script is opened from https://scripts.google.com instead of from the container.

1. Double-check that you are the container owner. If the container is stored in a Shared Drive, you should have permission to delete files from the Shared Drive.
2. If you can delete the container (see the previous point) and still are facing this problem, try using Chrome in incognito mode

   1. Open the container
   2. Click Extensions > Apps Script
   3. Click Overview, then click the trash / bin button.
3. Contact Google if you still can't delete the Apps Script project. This might take you nowhere, so if there isn't a good reason to continue working with the container, forget about it and use another container.